# What characters are NOT allowed in MongoDB field names?

Tags: mongodb

I figured out that of course . and SPACE aren't allowed. Are there other forbidden characters ?

Comment: Similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7976235/311220

Comment: SPACE is allowed.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

> You can use any (UTF8) character in the field name which aren't
>   special (contains ".", or starts with "$").

https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-3229

https://stackoverflow.com/a/7976235/311220

It's generally best to stick with lowercase alphanumeric with underscores though.

Comment: What about product specifications? Wouldn't it simplify the design greatly if the field names were the actual specification description? (e.g. `'Screen Size': '26 inches'`)

Comment: Not necessarily, @Dor - you want to have a bit of flexibility between your UI and your database (nothing so fickle as a customer: "Wait, I want it to say 'Display Size', not 'Screen Size'"). And of course, there's the whole internationalization part of the puzzle, requiring that decoupling too. By the way, when Acorn says 'any UTF8', that includes spaces, so you're perfectly OK there, if you want to.

Comment: How it will handle camel-cased words like `userDetails`? Is this valid?

Comment: @Dor is presenting a specific counter example to the claim that "It's generally best to stick with lowercase alphanumeric with underscores though." At a database layer, it's hard to make such claims without understanding better what the use-case is. In a document database like MongoDB, there are many potential use-cases where one might imagine using keys other than programmer-defined identifiers, and in that case, it's nice to know specifically which characters might be allowed or disallowed.

Comment: "/" is something I don't recommend because mongodump and mongorestore will have issues with it https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/TOOLS-1163

Comment: _"It's generally best to stick with lowercase alphanumeric with underscores though"_ this statement needs support/documentation/explanation.

Comment: "." is valid in MongoDB from version 3.6, but not recommended, see https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/limits/#naming-restrictions

Answer (score 1):

Something else to look out for is the fact that you can make a property name called "query" but then use query operators on it, making it awkward to do a large number of queries.

Example:

Insert document with a property named

```
db.coll.insert({ query: 'foo' });
```

Equality query works:

```
db.coll.findOne({ query: 'foo' });
```

Not equal ($ne) does not:

```
db.coll.findOne({ query: { $ne: 'bar' } });
```

Comment: Good point. But you can still do that query as `db.coll.findOne({query: {query: {$ne: 'bar'}}})`. So it's not impossible, but it is awkward.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't realize it wasn't impossible until after I posted this. Definitely more awkward.

Comment: As of 3.2 (released late 2015) this was fixed.