# Mongo $project _id of a reference collection

Tags: mongodb

I have the following document structure:

```
{
 "_id": ObjectId("52caafa2eccc222244f242cc"),
 "fields": {
     $id: ObjectId("52caafa2eccc222244f242cc"),
     $db: 'other_db',
     $ref: CollectionName 
  }
}
```

I am trying to project all the {id, fields.id} as following:

`db.Collection.find({},{"_id": 1, "fields._id": 1});`
but without any result

Comment: The `fields` subdocument has `$id` specified, not `_id`

Comment: tried the following `db.Collection.find({},{"_id": 1, "fields.$id": 1});`  getting the `Positional operator does not match the query specifier.` error

Comment: Well, the `$` could cause a problem. Does the field.id really contain a $ symbol?

Comment: @AlexandruOlaru check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9759972/what-characters-are-not-allowed-in-mongodb-field-names and mongo doc also mentioned this 

>Field names cannot contain dots (i.e. .) or null characters, and they must not start with a dollar sign (i.e. $)

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/limits/

Comment: @yogesh You should post that as an answer and recommended a new document structure without them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bad document structure, after reading the [MongoDb Reference Documentation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/limits) as advised by @yogesh the issue is caused by `$` sign in fron of each `Reference` key.