# Insert Html value in database inmeteor

Tags: javascript, json, meteor

In my meteor project in html a paragrap has json value like this.

```
    {"Active Template Id":"6467","Shirt Brand":"levis","ProductId":"EB301","Brand":"on","Material":"cotton","Price":"1800","Combo Id":"S90"}
```

i  want to store this value in database inside "products collection".
i am not geeting the exact solution to perform this.

Comment: Please add more info to your question, your current solution etc...

Comment: @Tomas you'll find a (detailed) duplicate [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/30476325/1439597)

Answer (score 0):

Your description about your question is too simple.
The general solution may include following steps:
step1:use ajax to send the data to the server.
step2:use the server script to receive and analysis it.
step3:insert into the database use circulation.