# Mongodb change Document field name

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-java

I have an application that reads a JSON String(not generated by me) that contains a field with a '.' and converts it to BSON as such:

```
Document document = new Document(Document.parse(jsonString));
```

Calling collection.insertOne() is causing me problems as mentioned in [What characters are NOT allowed in MongoDB field names?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9759972/what-characters-are-not-allowed-in-mongodb-field-names).

I'm now trying to change the field names within document that contain periods. Is there a way to iterate through the document and change the field names?

Answer (score 0):

I would point you towards db.collection.update(), something like:

```
db.collection.update({*your_find_query*},{$rename:{*fields_to_rename*}},{multi:true})
```

By setting **multi:true** you will update all the documents that match the query criteria.

More info: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/