# mongodb list of special or reserved characters for query

Tags: mongodb

Where can I find a list of special or reserved characters for querying in mongodb. I cannot find one online. Is it the same as the one for Javascript regexes?

I am looking for a list like the one provided by [elastic search](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html).

Comment: Are you asking [What characters are NOT allowed in MongoDB field names?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9759972/what-characters-are-not-allowed-in-mongodb-field-names)

Comment: Nope, I'm asking what characters are not allowed in a mongodb query - which may include field names, query strings, operators, regexes etc.